# How to make autoprefixer work with .vue files in Nuxt project?

Tags: nuxt.js, autoprefixer

I am building a nuxt application and using scss for styling.

I have installed `node-sass` and `sass-loader` & now am able to load external scss files. This global file is being processed by autoprefixer (for eg.: If I do `display: flex`, it automatically adds `display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox;`),

I have added these lines from doc to my `nuxt.config.js` file and have installed 4 pakcages as mentioned below (postcss-url, postcss-nested etc..)

```
postcss: {
            plugins: {
                'postcss-url': false,
                'postcss-nested': {},
                'postcss-responsive-type': {},
                'postcss-hexrgba': {}
            },
            preset: {
                autoprefixer: {
                    grid: true,
                    flexbox: true
                }
            }
        },
```

I expect my inline stylle with `lang="scss"` should also work in a same way as the global scss file(for eg.: If I do `display: flex`, it automatically adds `display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox;`).

Answer (score 5):

You can add in package.json after devDependencies - "browserslist": "cover 99.5%"

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you

```
preset: {
    autoprefixer: {
      flexbox: true,
      grid: true,
      overrideBrowserslist: ['last 3 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'],
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoprefixer should be enabled by default in Nuxt. If you want, you can adjust the settings. More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#postcss

Comment: It does works as separate scss file, but I would like to know how inline scss style work? I mean how autoprefixer can work inline also in single-file component.

Answer (score 0):

Autoprefixer should be enabled by default in Nuxt
I have used in my project and resolved for IE9 and above version

```
build: {
    postcss: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['cover 99.5%', 'not IE < 9']
      })
    ],
}
```